# Rails+Capybara+poltergeist ArgumentError: rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, phantomjs

I just started playing with Capycabra+poltergeist and after execution of my Capy test `rspec ./spec/features/test_spec.rb`
I got the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit '/item/new'
 ArgumentError: rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
```

Also I have a few standard  rspec tests and whenever I try to excute all tests, rspec tests are passed successfully, but only the capy test fails with weird error

```
ActionView::Template::Error: couldn't find file 'jquery.min' (in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)
```

Which leads me to the confusion.

I have viewed several similar threads on stackoverflow in some cases the error is about  missing **config.include Capybara::DSL in the spec_helper.rb** or incorrect location of tests. I made appropriate changes, but it doesn't work, the error is still the same.

My spec_helper.rb file

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Full Version of spec_helper: http://pastebin.com/qkANfu39

Test file:

```
#spec/features/test_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'
describe 'accessibility of webpage' do
  it 'should access web page' do
    visit '/item/new'
    expect(page).to have_content("Something")
  end

end
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Update

**This workaround is no longer needed according to the report(see in comments), but I haven't checked it yet.**

---

*Found workaround..*

I had to specify the app host url and a default driver..

```
#spec/spec_helper.rb

require 'capybara'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'


Capybara.configure do |c|
  c.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  c.default_driver = :poltergeist
  c.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"
end
```

## Update 1

In order to fix error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit '/item/new'
 ArgumentError: rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given
```

I included **rails_helper** file into my Capy test. the final version of test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'accessibility of webpage' do
  it 'should access web page' do
    visit '/item/new'
    expect(page).to have_content I18n.t("form_input.item.item_s")
  end
end
```

After that for some reason specified app_host url no longer needed and it can be removed from the   **spec_helper** helper file. The final version:

```
Capybara.configure do |c|
  c.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  c.default_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

The full  version of spec_helper.rb http://pastebin.com/DKgF1uQA

## Error

```
ActionView::Template::Error: couldn't find file 'jquery.min' (in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)
```

Occurred because gem 'jquery-rails' wasn't available in the test scope in my Gemfile, It was available only in :development & :production environment. I moved the gem 'jquery-rails' out to the global scope. The full version of a Gemfile:  http://pastebin.com/dt4KrHGG

Comment: with the latest version of cabybara, it works out of the box. i followed this post and could not get it to work, then i removed the code i copied from this post, then everything started working.

Comment: @ProblemSlover: Could you please edit to include the contents of the rails_helper.rb?  That is if you still have access to the source history from the state it was in when you asked this question?